# jQuery Contents() Find weight in MBs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to calculate the size of the content being pulled using contents ? I need to calculate it so that i can create an accurate page preloader. Currently an external pages contents are being pulled into a page on my site via ajax

Answer (score 1):

if you're getting content via ajax you can do something like this in your success call:

```
  success: function(msg){
      console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length') + ' bytes');
  }
```

Comment: This looks very interesting, I wont get a chance to test it until later but yeah I am doing it via ajax, Ive tried a couple of methods using the xhr response but none that work alongside measuring the actual size of the content Im pulling in